# How are the best director award winners chosen?

Tags: directors, film-industry, awards

I do not understand how the best director awards are determined each year. It seems impossible to assess the method of a movie director unless you are part of the crew.

So, how do the nominators/judges assess the directors' performance each year?

Comment: What award ceremony are you referring to as there are a lot of them.  The main one for Hollywood movies are the Oscars, for example

Comment: Most of the Best Directors awards, Oscar is one of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7352334_decides-wins-oscars_.html):

> *In Hollywood, the nominating and selecting for the Oscars are done by the writers, actors, directors, animators, art directors and executives. The only requirement is that each participant be a part of the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences.*

Members of AMPAS are courted by film studios with free screeners, gifts and social evenings in the run up for most award ceremonies. Considering how much extra revenue is on the line when a film wins an award, the expense of these promotions are considered well worth it.

When I was a member of the Animator's Guild, I would be sent screeners of the major films released that year, along with cells from the films, making of books, postcards, whatever would work to secure my vote.

Then the nomination ballots are mailed to all AMPAS members, usually in December, and they have a limited amount of time to get their votes in.

**In the case of the directors' awards**, your statement *'It seems impossible to assess the method of a movie director unless you are part of the crew'* is correct, but the directors are being assessed on their output, not their method. Subject matter can be a great influence, as can the current zeitgeist or even a really solid marketing campaign. It's a general rule of thumb that films picking up awards early in the season jump on the rollercoaster and pick up speed all the way to the Oscars.

Comment: This answer leaves out a crucial aspect: If the directors are judged based only on their output, what is the difference between Best Director and Best Picture? It seems that the directing itself, i.e. the method, must play a role here. Which are the factors, observable by the Oscar jury, that can make a movie worthy of one award but not the other?

Comment: Best director would be for a single person or small group. Best Picture would be that group plus all the others involved: writers, actors, costumers, musicians etal. So while someone may win best director, they may not be the best of the rest of the crew. While a so so director, can be part of Best Picture because the crew pulled it off.

Comment: @DCook Would you like to expand that comment into a complete answer, possibly with references?

Comment: Well eyes would be a good choice. When they announce best director, only the director(s) go up. When they announce best picture, you get the director, cast, writer. So pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: I thought that only other directors voted for best director, actors for best actor, etc., with the only exception being that all academy members vote for best picture. Is this not (or no longer) the case?

Comment: To me it seems clearly false to say you have to see a director at work to know their methods, or even to know that a new method was developed. I'm not a director and have only worked on student films, but I know a crane shot from a jib shot from a helicopter shot from a steadicam shot from a CGI shot, etc., just from watching the film. It's not always clear what was the work of the director versus the DP, but since the director is the overall boss, they get the overall credit. That's totally leaving aside coaxing great performances from actors, which is also clear to many.

Comment: @Jakob A movie can have a mediocre story but amazing directing. One obvious way a movie can have a single aspect better than others is special effects. A movie can be pretty bad and still have amazing effects, and it doesn't take much film experience to see it. Seeing the difference between the work of the director and the work of the producer (the winner of a best picture award) is a lot more difficult and subtle, but it's pretty clear to members of the Academy, who are all working film professionals.

Comment: I see the role of a director, in terms of elevating the quality of a movie, as the successful execution of a creative vision. While each of the major crew members, such as production directors, art directors, music directors, etc. may try to maximize the quality of their work, the job of a director is to make sure that the work each of these teams produce coalesce into an overall product greater then the sum of those parts.

A movie can be really good because of the immense quality of individual aspects of the movie, but may not feel like a fully realized creative vision.